# Dates into textarea

Tags: jquery, html, forms, format

I have a custom datepicker thing it put puts dayes like this

```
05 November
06 November
23 November
```

i add my dates to my div with this

```
date = '<div class=form-field-fulldate>'+$('#month').val()+" "+ $('#day').val()+" "+$('#time').val()+'</div>';
$('#date-list').append(date);
```

I want to take the value of my div and add them as plain text with a line break into a (hidden) textarea so when  I submit the form I get the output like it is above.

I have tried val but I just  get all the html inserted too.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: JQueryUI datepicker provides methods to parse and format dates. You could have a js Date variable. Each time ou need it, just parse it. `$.datepicker.parseDate('dd MMM', '05/04/2010');` But You will have to add some code to use textual months name I guess.

Answer (score 0):

After appending the date you can set it to a new line. like this

//Date appended

```
$('#hiddentextBlock').append(date);
```

//Insert a line break.

```
$('#hiddentextBlock').html() = $('#date-list').html() + "&#13;&#10;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to put the content of the `<div>` inside the textarea:

```
$('#textareaID').val($('.form-field-fulldate').html());
```